# Positioning a formula and a table side by side

Tags: tables, equations

I have created a table and I have two formulae. 
The result of my code is as below:

[image]

but I want to produce the following:

[image]

my code:

```
    \begin{flushleft}
    \lr{
        \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
            $a$&$b$&$S$&$C$\\
            \hline
            0&0&0&0\\
            0&1&1&0\\
            1&0&1&0\\
            1&1&0&1\\
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{flushleft}

\begin{equation*}
S=\bar{a}b+a\bar{b}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
C=ab
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
   \documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
            $a$&$b$&$S$&$C$\\
            \hline
            0&0&0&0\\
            0&1&1&0\\
            1&0&1&0\\
            1&1&0&1\\
        \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}&
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
S=\bar{a}b+a\bar{b}\notag
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C=ab\notag
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `minipage` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
        $a$&$b$&$S$&$C$\\
        \hline
        0&0&0&0\\
        0&1&1&0\\
        1&0&1&0\\
        1&1&0&1\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
% note: no newline here!
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{equation*}
    S=\bar{a}b+a\bar{b}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
    C=ab
    \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: latex minipage]

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the two equation lines together, because they seems to be a legend for the symbols in the header for the right half of the table. The following example aligns them at the equal signs in the first in the first case. Then the equations are aligned at the left. Also the example shows two possible vertical
alignments for the table and equations: same math axis around the middle or at the base line of the top lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
  a & b & S & C \\
  \hline
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
\end{array}$\qquad
$\begin{aligned}
  S &= \bar{a}b + a\bar{b}\\
  C &= ab
\end{aligned}$

\medskip

\noindent
$\begin{array}[t]{cc|cc}
  a & b & S & C \\
  \hline
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
\end{array}$\qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
  & S = \bar{a}b + a\bar{b}\\
  & C = ab
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or the formulas could be integrated in the table, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
    &   & S                   & C \\
  a & b & \bar{a}b + a\bar{b} & ab\\
  \hline
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

or all put in one table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}|*{2}{>{$}c<{$}} *{2}{>{$}l<{$}}}
a   &   b   &   S   &   C   &   \qquad  &   S=\bar{a}b+a\bar{b} \\
    \cline{1-4}
0   &   0   &   0   &   0   &           &   \\
0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &           &   \\
1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &           &   \\
1   &   1   &   0   &   1   &           &   C=ab
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have bigger distance between table and equation, than replace `\qquad` with `\hspace*{<desired distance>}`.